# SQL : 12 hr shift function from 7am - 7am

Tags: sql, function

I need to query all production records by 12 hr. shift.  7am-7am.  if the date is after midnight and before 7am it's actually the previous day shift.  In the below example I need to make them all 2022-01-01 like the last column.  If I query by 2022-01-01 I don't get all the rows. Can I use a function for this to compare the time and make it the previous day?

```
declare @temp table 
              (
                  Emp_id int,   
                  Time datetime,
                  shiftDate date
              );

insert into @temp values (1, '2022-01-01 08:10:00:000', '2022-01-01')
insert into @temp values (1, '2022-01-01 10:21:00:000', '2022-01-01')
insert into @temp values (1, '2022-01-01 13:10:00:000', '2022-01-01')
insert into @temp values (1, '2022-01-01 22:22:00:000', '2022-01-01')
insert into @temp values (1, '2022-01-02 02:15:00:000', '2022-01-01')
insert into @temp values (1, '2022-01-02 04:22:00:000', '2022-01-01')
insert into @temp values (1, '2022-01-02 06:18:00:000', '2022-01-01')
insert into @temp values (1, '2022-01-02 06:55:00:000', '2022-01-01')

select * from @temp 

select * from @temp 
where convert(date, [time]) = '2022-01-01'
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Can you provide an expected output based on the input you did include? Thank you for that by the way, it is rare that a question initially includes a table with data population.

Comment: SQL 2019 and the @temp is just an example.   I would like my results to show all the rows as 2022-01-01 so I can group/sum by that date.  This will include a lot of other dates in the same query as a range.